# Is there a way to keep pipeline runs of pullrequests indefinitely?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our project is in a regulated area and we need to show that the PR Test results have been successfully run in case of audits even 1,2 years later. Therefore we need the PR Pipeline builds to remain and not get deleted.

I have managed to store Pipeline build related to the main branch using the protected retention policy.
I have managed to store Pipeline build related to the release.

I cannot find how to store the PR Pipelines for longer than 30 days:

[image]

My only idea is to manually go and select "Retain" on the builds.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API [Update Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). The PowerShell example to keep all builds of one build definition:

```powershell
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>" #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$org = "<org_name>"
$teamProject = "<team_project_name>"
$buildDefId = "<build_definition_id>"

$restApiGetBuilds = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$buildDefId&api-version=6.0"
$restApiPatchBuildTemplate = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0"

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}

function InvokePatchRequest ($GetUrl, $body)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}


$builds = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetBuilds

foreach($build in $builds.value)
{
    $restApiPatchBuild = $restApiPatchBuildTemplate -replace "{buildId}", $build.id

    InvokePatchRequest $restApiPatchBuild '{"keepForever":true}'
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I would have hoped that AZD would support somehow this functionality, but what you sent is an amazing hack! if noone else adds anything in short time, I will mark this as an answer. Thank you again!